# query to_date issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Below query is giving me two different result for two different oracle database. ( database version I am not aware of )

I want to ask like `TO_DATE` function varies from database version ?

```
select * from ACC WHERE CHANGE = TO_DATE('01/02/2015','MM/DD/YY');
```

Note that I am facing issue in only `=` but `<` and `>` working fine.

In 1 db : this query is giving 1 record

In 2 db : this query is giving 0 record.

In DB : CHANGE value is 02-JAN-14

Comment: What is type of CHANGE column, DATE ?

Comment: Yes..it is of type DATE

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `to_date()` hasn't changed.  More likely is that you have a time component on your column `change`, which prevents `=` from working.  Try this:

```
select *
from ACC
where trunc(CHANGE) = TO_DATE('01/02/2015','MM/DD/YY');
```

Or, how I would prefer to write this:

```
where change >= DATE '2015-01-02' and
      change < (DATE '2015-01-02') + 1
```

Using the `date` keyword, you can use ISO standard formats.  This version also allows the use of indexes on the `change` column.

Comment: trunc is working.But I cannot see time component in both the database table value. I am using oracle sql developer.

Comment: @vjs . . . You can use `to_char()` to convert the value to a string and see the time component.

Comment: I did select to_char(change) from...., but there is not time component in both the db table values

Comment: `to_char(change, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` or just look at `change - trunc(change)`.

Answer (score 0):

if they are on the same server is strange. If you are on two different servers verify that the date format of the server is the same.

You can see it in the settings under NLS